# Does iTextSharp support Universal Windows App 10?

Tags: .net, uwp, windows-phone

Does iTextSharp support Universal Windows  App 10? I am trying to create PDFs from a C# UWP App, but `PdfWriter.GetInstance` requires some arguments which is not available in UWP 10. is there any other tool for creation pdf file in UWP 10?

Comment: I tried to download the nuget package but it said that it was incompatible with UWP. :( Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Considering other solutions that you ask at the end there is PDFSharp, I have tested it to work, but frequently it doesn't import documents properly (but as you want only to output it may work).

There are many other solutions like Xfinium, but they are paid (though iTextSharp requires you to pay much more hefty license if you are not open source project, so it might be OK for you if you haven't overlooked that fact).